# How to replace and shift the string pattern in python using re?

Tags: python, regex, scala

I have a snippet like

```
re.sub(r"""\s*(\p{LD}+)\s+NEAR/(\d)\s+(\p{LD}+)\s*""",r""""$1 $3"~$2""",'foo NEAR/4 bar')
```

in python.

expected output is
**"foo bar"~4**

but now i am getting

```
foo NEAR/4 bar
```

i am trying to convert a scala code to python. 
scala code is

```
val near_rex = """\s*(\p{LD}+)\s+NEAR/(\d)\s+(\p{LD}+)\s*""".r;
val out = near_rex.replaceAllIn("foo NEAR/4 bar", """"$1 $3"~$2""");
```

scala snippet is working fine here http://www.simplyscala.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know scala, so I don't know what `\p{LD}+` is supposed to match but using `\w` to match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (foo/bar), the regexp is ok:

```
>>> re.sub(r"""\s*(\w+)\s+NEAR/(\d)\s+(\w+)\s*""",r""""\1 \3"~\2""",'foo NEAR/4 bar')
'"foo bar"~4'
```

In order to return the captured groups, you have to use `\1`, `\2`... instead of `$1`.

---

As suggested by Avinash Raj in comments, you can get rid of triples quotes by using simple ones:

```
re.sub(r'\s*(\w+)\s+NEAR/(\d)\s+(\w+)\s*',r'"\1 \3"~\2','foo NEAR/4 bar')
```

Furthermore `\p{L}` is not Scala-specific (credits to Amal Murali), but is used to match a unicode character belonging to the ["letter" category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category).

Comment: Why are confusing with the quotes? Just `re.sub(r'\s*(\w+)\s+NEAR/(\d)\s+(\w+)\s*',r'"\1 \3"~\2','foo NEAR/4 bar')` would be fine.

Comment: `\p{LD}+` is not a Scala-specific thing. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html (under "*Unicode Categories*").